# return http responses while using event-stream

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, server-sent-events

I may be doing something wrong here, design-wise, so alternatives are welcome (but syntax is preferred)..

Using .NET Core 3.1 & API Application, I want to:

1. Have endpoints that return *IActionResult*, such as this:

   ```
    public IActionResult GetById(int id)
    {                
         return Ok(product);
    }
   ```
2. Use Server-Sent Events, such as this:

   ```
   [HttpGet]
   public async Task Get()
   {
       var response = Response;
       response.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "text/event-stream");
       for (var i = 0; true; ++i)
       {
           await response.WriteAsync($"data: Controller {i} at {DateTime.Now}\r\r");
           response.Body.Flush();
           await Task.Delay(5 * 1000);
       }
   }
   ```

They don't really play along together, and I think I understand why:

1. second code example changes header, which sets `Response.HasStarted` to `true`
2. first code example creates (?) a new response object, or just tries to set its status to 200, which is not possible - since `Response.HasStarted` is set, which throws the following exception:

`System.InvalidOperationException: StatusCode cannot be set, response has already started.`

For now, I chose code example two (not returning IActionResult). But once I do start sending the data, it's kinda hard to report errors.. Am I doomed to reporting erros via server-sent events as well? Also, what if i want my "final" response to be unrelated to the previously sent data, but still in belong to the same response, so I DO want a 200 with some JSON object, such as this:

```
data: {income: 3}
data: {income: 4}
data: {income: 5}
{something-unrelated: 'hello'} //http response, not sse
```

Comment: as a side note, i've tried to report errors as events, but also with no success. the following: `event: error \n\n data: {}` is not caught

Comment: What is avgIncome, do you want to calculate its value in real time?

Comment: @Karney. i updated my question to clarify. it does not have to be as "real time" as the previous messages, just on the same response.